# Unable to install Elementary Tweaks on 5.1 Hera

Tags: release-hera, repositories

I followed a guide to install Tweaks but I'm stucked at repository step, because I'm unable to add It because of a error;

The command I pasted in terminal was:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks`

And this is what the terminal gives me in output:

`Error: retrieving gpg key timed out.`

I tried searching on Google but none seems to have this problem, none seems using Hera at least...

P.S. I installed the `software-properties-common`

Comment: Same story here...
Elementary OS 5.1, i cannot achieve any sort of installation.
<pre>$ sudo apt install elementary-tweaks
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package elementary-tweaks"</pre>

Comment: Have you already added the repository? Your error log is different from mine

Comment: To install elementary tweaks: `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:philip.scott/elementary-tweaks
sudo apt install elementary-tweaks`

Answer (score 0):

"Elementary Tweaks" is for eos Juno and below.

"Pantheon Tweaks" (which is a fork of "Elementary Tweaks") is for Odin but it works fine on my Hera.

https://github.com/pantheon-tweaks/pantheon-tweaks/

(here you will find the commands to install it from PPA or from source code)

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this issue before.
In my case, it was IPv6 that caused the problem.
Fixing this is described in [this AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/787491/1117671).
You can set your system to prefer IPv4 over IPv6 by uncommenting the following line in `/etc/gai.conf`.

```
# precedence ::ffff:0:0/96 100
```